# CrudRepository save method not returning updated entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working with Spring and in it `spring-data-jpa:1.7.0.RELEASE` and `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final`. My database is a MySQL. In a integration test, when I save an entity, the `entityRepository.save()` method does not return a update version of it (with the auto-incremented id populated for example), thus I can see it is in the database.

Here's my configuration class:

```
//@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "core.repository")
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private
    @Value("${db.driverClassName}")
    String driverClassName;
    private
    @Value("${db.url}")
    String url;
    private
    @Value("${db.username}")
    String user;
    private
    @Value("${db.password}")
    String password;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(user);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"core.persistence"});
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.afterPropertiesSet();


        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
}
```

Here's my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JPAConfiguration.class})
//@Transactional
//@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class AgencyRepositoryIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    AgencyRepository agencyRepository;

    @Test
    public void testThatAgencyIsSavedIntoRepoWorks() throws Exception {

        Agency c = DomainTestData.getAgency();
        Agency d = agencyRepository.save(c);
        // here d equals to c but both have id 0.

        Collection<Agency> results = Lists.newArrayList(agencyRepository.findAll());
        //here results != null and it does contain the agency object.
        assertNotNull(results);
    }
}
```

I end up commenting the Transactional annotations (both in the test and in the configuration class) due to research other questions in stackoverflow, but it did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to uncomment your @Transactional annotation and run. I can't see any visible problem in your snippet but there is something inside me (and it's not hunger) saying that your transaction demarcation is not right. I had similar problems like this before and it was just @transaction annotations missing or transaction misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Use saveAndFlush method to make sure that the entity is in the database.

Make sure to add @Transactional to your methods if a NoTransactionException appears.

Comment: Where does saveAndFlush method came from? The CrudRepository interface does not have such method...

Comment: Use the JPARepository interface instead.

Comment: I Just notice that you are not using JPA, my BAD. Try use the @Transactional instead.